# Set http code for Symfony constraint validation failure

Tags: php, rest, symfony, http, doctrine

Shortly: how can you set a specific http error code, instead of a generic 500, when a constraint fails on entity save?

## Details

I'm using Symfony custom constraint `@UniqueEntity` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to assert that some data is not duplicated when saving an entity.

If this constraint check results in a violation, I get a 500 http code, while others may be more appropriate, e.g. 409 - Conflict (https://httpstatuses.com/409).

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to override the validation response.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for the UniqueEntity constraint ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière no but you can use an actual constraint like this
     * @ORM\Table(name="company", uniqueConstraints={
     *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="code_idx", columns={"code"})
     * })

Comment: Isn't this similar to @UniqueEntity() ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière yes, but a correct exception is thrown. See my last comment in the accepted answer below.

Comment: Oh ok, you didn't mention that you had to add this constraint in your last comment

Comment: Yes, I pointed you to that comment to explain the **reason** I had to use a different annotation. Hope this helps.

Comment: How am I supposed to add multiple UniqueConstraint using this syntax please ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière this is unrelated to original question. Please post a new question instead.

Comment: When I'm removing the @UniqueEntity annotation, I can now add multiple same email, what am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch exception in controller:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    try {
       $entity = new Entity('duplicate name');

       $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
       $this->entityManager->flush();

       return new Response();
    } catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
       return new Response('Entity with same name already exists', Response::HTTP_CONFLICT);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       return new Response('Internal error', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is a good idea as well, even simpler than the listener! I will try. P.S. there's a typo in the code, missing quote after "duplicate name".

Comment: thank you, your solution works fine but I had to remove the `@UniqueEntity` annotation to let the correct exception come through. So this is the best answer assuming you don't use the `@UniqueEntity` annotation. You may want to edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a [Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) to the event : `kernel.exception`

And then you will have something like :

```
<?php

public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
      $e = $event->getException();

      if ($e instanceof NameOfTheException) {
            // logic here

            return (new Response())
                  ->setStatusCode(409)
            ;
      }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that is a creative workaround, I will try it and it may fix my need. Unfortunately I feel it's not the "correct" answer (maybe there isn't one).